# Using the values of some columns in a data.table to determine which remaining columns will be used

Tags: r, data.table

Here is my data set,

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(
  id = 1:8, 
  start = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2), 
  end = c(1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2), 
  t1 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), 
  t2 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), 
  t3 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
)
df

> tmp
   id start end t1 t2 t3
1:  1     1   1  0  0  0
2:  2     2   3  1  0  1
3:  3     2   3  1  1  1
4:  4     1   3  1  1  1
5:  5     3   3  1  1  0
6:  6     3   3  0  1  1
7:  7     1   2  1  0  0
8:  8     2   2  0  1  1
```

For each row, I want to create a column `x` and assign it to `TRUE` if column `paste0(t, start)` to `paste0(t, end)` are all `1`'s, `FALSE` otherwise.

So the desired output should be

```
   id start end t1 t2 t3     x
1:  1     1   1  0  0  0 FALSE # t1 is 0
2:  2     2   3  1  0  1 FALSE # t2 is 0
3:  3     2   3  1  1  1  TRUE # t2 to t3 are all 1
4:  4     1   3  1  1  1  TRUE # t1 to t3 are all 1
5:  5     3   3  1  1  0 FALSE # t3 is 0
6:  6     3   3  0  1  1  TRUE # t3 is 1
7:  7     1   2  1  0  0 FALSE # t2 is 0
8:  8     2   2  0  1  1  TRUE # t2 is 1
```

Is it possible for me to achieve my goal without using for-loop on each row? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `melt` the dataset from 'wide' to 'long', then grouped by 'id', we get the elements of 'value' that corresponds to the sequence between 'start' and 'end', and check if `all` the values are not equal to 0.  The output will be a logical vector which we can assign it to the original dataset as 'x'.

```
df[, x:=melt(.SD, measure = 4:6)[, 
       all(value[start[1L]:end[1L]]!=0), id]$V1]
df
#  id start end t1 t2 t3     x
#1:  1     1   1  0  0  0 FALSE
#2:  2     2   3  1  0  1 FALSE
#3:  3     2   3  1  1  1  TRUE
#4:  4     1   3  1  1  1  TRUE
#5:  5     3   3  1  1  0 FALSE
#6:  6     3   3  0  1  1  TRUE
#7:  7     1   2  1  0  0 FALSE
#8:  8     2   2  0  1  1  TRUE
```

---

Or we group by the sequence of rows

```
df[, x:={nm1 <- names(df)[(start:end)+3L]
   list( Reduce(`+`, .SD[, nm1, with=FALSE])==length(nm1)) }
          , 1:nrow(df)]
df
# id start end t1 t2 t3     x
#1:  1     1   1  0  0  0 FALSE
#2:  2     2   3  1  0  1 FALSE
#3:  3     2   3  1  1  1  TRUE
#4:  4     1   3  1  1  1  TRUE
#5:  5     3   3  1  1  0 FALSE
#6:  6     3   3  0  1  1  TRUE
#7:  7     1   2  1  0  0 FALSE
#8:  8     2   2  0  1  1  TRUE
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do the same job for a big data set (e.g. tens of thousands of row, and a hundred `t` columns)? `melt` takes a lot of time to 'transform' the structure of the data set.

Answer (score 2):

We can write a function to do this for each dataframe row and then apply it row by row

```
df$x <- apply(df,1,function(x) {all(x[ (x[2]+3) : (x[3]+3) ]==1)})
```

The inline function accepts a row of data from the dataframe and then gets the appropriate columns from this row (`x[2]` is the start value, so `x[2]+3` gives the starting t column and similar for `x[3]+3`) and checks these against the value 1, returning if they are all 1 or not.

The `apply` function applies this inline function to each row of the dataframe (the value of 1 for the second argument means to work by row) and returns the results for each row.  We then assign this to the dataframe.

After running this, `df` looks like

```
   id start end t1 t2 t3     x
1:  1     1   1  0  0  0 FALSE
2:  2     2   3  1  0  1 FALSE
3:  3     2   3  1  1  1  TRUE
4:  4     1   3  1  1  1  TRUE
5:  5     3   3  1  1  0 FALSE
6:  6     3   3  0  1  1  TRUE
7:  7     1   2  1  0  0 FALSE
8:  8     2   2  0  1  1  TRUE
```

as desired.